# How to display same post in 2 forums

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953733/test-driven-design-and-layered-architecture) on stackoverflow.

Fellow user suggested that it is better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com. Thus i had flagged the question to migrate into programmers.stackexchange.com.

Now the worry is, programmers.SE.com does not have that wider contributors/members as stackoverflow.com has. So Once question is migrated, many members will not be able to answer this question on SO.

Is it possible to display the same post on both SO, and Programmers.SE.com?

Comment: Regardless of the number of users, the question is off topic on SO, so it shouldn't be here.

Comment: off topic seems subjective. I feel question makes better sense on programmers.SE.com, but it is off topic on SO as well. There are many overlapping (similar) questions at more then one site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.

Once it is migrated it is closed on the site it came from as "migrated"

---

You can always reask it again on the original site, but this is **not** suggested.

Comment: In fact, it's strongly discouraged and frowned upon.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that too.